# Pyserial and asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Trying to use pyserial with asyncio on a windows machine.

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27927704/1629704 my code is constantly watching a serial port for incoming data.

```
# This coroutine is added as a task to the event loop.
@asyncio.coroutine
def get_from_serial_port(self):
    while 1:
        serial_data = yield from self.get_byte_async()
        <doing other stuff with serial_data>

# The method which gets executed in the executor
def get_byte(self):
    data = self.s.read(1)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    tst = self.s.read(self.s.inWaiting())
    data += tst
    return data

# Runs blocking function in executor, yielding the result
@asyncio.coroutine
def get_byte_async(self):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        res = yield from self.loop.run_in_executor(executor, self.get_byte)
        return res
```

After serial data has been returned. the coroutine `get_byte_async` is called inside the while loop creating a new executor. I always learned creating a new thread is expensive so I feel I should take another approach, but I am not sure how to do that.
I've been reading this article https://hackernoon.com/threaded-asynchronous-magic-and-how-to-wield-it-bba9ed602c32#.964j4a5s7

And I guess I need to do the reading of the serial port in another thread. But how to get the serial data back to the "main" loop ?

Comment: Check the implementation of aioserial. https://github.com/changyuheng/aioserial

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the default executor and lock the access to `get_byte` with an [asyncio lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock):

```
async def get_byte_async(self):
    async with self.lock:
        return await self.loop.run_in_executor(None, self.get_byte)
```

Or simply create your own executor once:

```
async def get_byte_async(self):
    if self.executor is None:
        self.executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    return await self.loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, self.get_byte)
```